# Как через консоль в браузере обратиться к переменным в модулях JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, консоль, модули

При работе с обычным скриптом в JavaScript (без `type="module"` в `<script...`), к глобальным переменным можно легко обратиться через консоль в браузере, введя имя переменной. А как это делать, когда работаешь с модулями? В этом случае консоль выдает `ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

Работа модулей осуществляется с помощью расширения Live Server для VSCode.

Comment: засунуть необходимую переменную в объект window. `window.abc = 123`

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {ajax} from './ajax.js'
window.ajax = ajax

let x = 5
window.x = x
```